# Magento 2.3.5 admin password reset link expired

Tags: magento2.3.5, password-recovery

If I try to reset password via admin login's "forgot password?" functionality, the link sent to reset password is expired immediately. I have the Recovery Link Expiration Period set to 10 hours. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get this fixed?  we are having the same issue

Comment: have the same issue.. how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the default email template `vendor/magento/module-user/view/adminhtml/email/password_reset_confirmation.html`

IS:

```
{{store url="admin/auth/resetpassword/" _query_id=$user.id _query_token=$user.rp_token _nosid=1}}
```

SHOULD:

```
{{store url="admin/auth/resetpassword/" _query_id=$user.user_id _query_token=$user.rp_token _nosid=1}}
```

Replace `id` with `user_id`.

Of course, you shouldn't do that change in the file directly (otherwise it's gone on the next update), but in a copy in your own theme or by using the "Email Templates" backend functionality.